# Difference between unifrnd and rand() functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I am a little bit confuse about use of `rand()` and `unifrnd()` in interval [0,1]. How are both different? Definitions of these from Matlab tutorial are as follows:

```
rand() - Uniformly distributed pseudorandom numbers 
unifrnd() - Continuous uniform random numbers
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean [`unifrnd`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/unifrnd.html), (not "`unifrand`").

`unifrnd` is part of the Statistics Toolbox, whereas `rand` is a Matlab basic function.

`unifrand` is just a wrapper of `rand` that lets you specify additional parameters to define the interval of the random values (`rand` outputs values in [0,1]). You could do the same with `rand` using `(a-b)*rand(...)+b`, where `a` and `b` is the desired interval. Type `open unifrnd` in Matlab to see `unifrnd`'s code.

Another difference is that, in recent Matlab versions, [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) lets you specify the data type of the generated output: `single` or `double`.